# Fix touchpad issue/Update touchpad drivers in HP PC Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, mouse, touchpad, hp

I am using an HP Pavilion laptop with an ELAN touchpad device, and on Ubuntu, I can not click using my touchpad. I can just drag my mouse around with the touchpad, but not click, right click or do any other action. If I use a touchpad, even by mistake, my external mouse does not work. To fix this (temporarily) I use <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd> and this gets my external mouse working again. How can I fix this permanently and how can I get my touchpad to work?

Comment: If you need any information from my system, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the ubuntu along with updating the mousepad driver. Because some times there will error in loading the files.